Republican and Social Conservative Manifesto
Is there any Manifesto outlining basic GOP and Social Conservative values? Regarding the latter, I want a nonchristian and if possible a neutral version for the USA.

It's not very clear what you are asking here.  Do you want something like the Conservative party manifesto, a document written by a particular party for a particular election to promote themselves, or something like the "communist manifesto" Written to promote ideas (but not by or for a particular party) Or an academic style text that neutrally describes the movement.

@JamesK the latter mainly

In 2020 the Republican Party reissued its 2016 platform. They will likely issue a new one for 2024 but as of right now that's their most official statement of values. There's no "nonchristian" version: it is what is. Politics is never "neutral" either, but this is their own official document and not someone else's representation.
That's the GOP. There is no official representative of "Social Conservative values" in the US, but if you want to understand how conservativism historically became a coherent movement strongly associated with the Republican Party, I recommend you to read up about William Buckley and Ronald Reagan.

By nonChristian version, I don't mean one where Christian values are eradicated more one which is written to cater to a more global audience.

The GOP platform is for a national audience for sure. Global might be a stretch.

They mention Christian 8 times in the 66 pages, BTW.

@againstverylongusernames okay, but it's not like made for the Christian audience specifically, but for all GOP members correct?
